# How to Plot the solution of the heat equation on rectangle

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to get the solution of the heat equation on the rectangle $(0,a)\times (0,b)$ with initial condition $u(x,y,0)=g(x)$, using the usual analytical method (by expanding as a series of eigenfunctions, call them $X(x), Y(y)$).

Here's my code

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = 1;
b = 2;
g[x_, y_] := x + y
mu[m_] := (m*π)/a
nu[n_] := (n*π)/b
X[m_, x_] := Sin[mu[m]*x]
Y[n_, y_] := Cos[nu[n]*y]
l[m_, n_] := π^2*(m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2)
phi[m_, n_, x_, y_] := 2/Sqrt[a*b]*Sin[mu[m]*x]*Sin[nu[n]*y]

A[m_, n_] := 
 Integrate[Integrate[g[x, y]*phi[m, n, x, y], {y, 0, b}], {x, 0, a}]


u[x_, y_, t_, nmax1_, nmax2_] := 
 Sum[Sum[A[m, n]*E^(-l[m, n]*t)*phi[m, n, x, y], {n, 1, nmax2}], {m, 
   1, nmax1}]

u[x, y, t, 5, 5]




Animate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x, y, u[x, y, t, 5, 5]}], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
  PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Mesh -> True, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1 , 1}], {t, 0, 10, 0.0001}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]

ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{x, y, u[x, y, 10, 5, 5]}], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
 PlotRange -> All, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]]
```

$l[m,n]$ denotes the eigenvalues, $phi [m,n,x,y]$ denotes the combined eigenfunctions and $A[m,n]$ are the Fourier coefficients.

Although I get the solution, the plot doesn't quite work, can you help me fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work?"  Does it spit out an error message? Is it not what you were expecting? It seems fine to me.

Comment: Obviously the animation is not a good idea, because the rendering of the plot takes too long, but otherwise this seems to be doing what it should.

Answer (score 5):

A few observations.

1. It is generally better to use a fixed `PlotRange` rather than `All` for an animation so your scale is not constantly changing.
2. `Animate` can be very slow for complicated plots, especially when you are trying to plot 100000 frames. Make a table of plots and then `ListAnimate`, but not for 100000 frames.  Your animation will be much smoother.
3. Know your data.  Your plot damps out to nothing way before `t = 10`.

That said, try:

```
tp = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    Evaluate[{x, y, u[x, y, t, 5, 5]}], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 4}, BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
    ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Mesh -> True, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> 600], {t, 0, .25, .01}];

ListAnimate[tp]
```

[image]

The table will take awhile to create, but once you have that, your animation should be smooth.

Answer (score 4):

- `u[x, y, t, 5, 5]` is too small when `t` is large. Here we set `{t, 0, 2}`.
- Replace `:=` to `=` make faster.
- We can use one `Sum` and one `Integrate`.
- We can use `Plot3D`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1;
b = 2;
g[x_, y_] = x + y;
mu[m_] = (m*π)/a;
nu[n_] = (n*π)/b;
X[m_, x_] = Sin[mu[m]*x];
Y[n_, y_] = Cos[nu[n]*y];
l[m_, n_] = π^2*(m^2/a^2 + n^2/b^2);
phi[m_, n_, x_, y_] = 2/Sqrt[a*b]*Sin[mu[m]*x]*Sin[nu[n]*y];
A[m_, n_] = Integrate[g[x, y]*phi[m, n, x, y], {y, 0, b}, {x, 0, a}];
u[x_, y_, t_, nmax1_, nmax2_] := 
  Sum[A[m, n]*E^(-l[m, n]*t)*phi[m, n, x, y], {n, 1, nmax2}, {m, 1, 
    nmax1}];
u[x, y, t, 5, 5]
Animate[Plot3D[u[x, y, t, 5, 5] // Evaluate, {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, a}, {0, b}, {0, 4}}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", Mesh -> True, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {t, 0, 2}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]